# Remove School, shops from MKMapKit in iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit

I need to show only route in map in ios. I have to set false to **showsPointsOfInterest** but did not hide school, shop on the map.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: its the bug in mapkit

Answer (score 1):

This bug is present in Swift 4 & Objective C also, the bug filed in the   Product Version:    **11.2.5** , the bug created on  2017-12-28.you get the detail info in  Community bug reports for [**showsPointsOfInterest**](http://www.openradar.me/36226715) and the bug `status` is `open`.

if you need the feature , then customize yourself use foursquare map and draw your point